# Is it a necessary to have at least one class in C#

Tags: c#, class, program-entry-point

In Java, we need to have at least a class to hold the main method.

When I create a C# project, the skeleton code looks similar to the Java skeleton codes.

However, should there always be at least one class for the main function in C#?

```
namespace Hello_World
{
    class Hello   //Is it compulsory to have this class ?
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I am assuming at least one class is needed in a most basic C# program as the main method needs to be contain within a class. Since main() is needed to run a program, at least one class is needed. Am I right to say that?

Comment: Yes the smallest unit of a code is still a class. So yes you need the class

Comment: @damola you forgot about `struct`, refer my answer ;)

Comment: Give this a read. It'll help :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx

Answer (score 12):

No, not necessarily. You can have a `struct` also. Following is a perfectly valid c# program.

```
namespace NoClass
{
    struct Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

Fact that `Method` should be inside a type in `c#` you need a enclosing type for your main method. It can be `struct` or `class`. It is your choice. but you can't have global funcions in c#.

Comment: So we need a struct or a class and no other possibilities, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [CS-Script](http://www.csscript.net/), which is a way to use C# similarly to scripting languages, it's able to execute code without a class.

Granted, that's hardly traditional C#.

Answer (score 0):

Since C# has not a code container/scope that can hold variables and functions - like modules in F# or VB - then yes, you have to define a type (class or struct and not a structural type; which in this scope would be an interface) to hold your code.

In fact you can not have any code out of a class or struct in C# (enum and assembly level attributes does not count!).